# How to trigger an effect after an event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, material-ui

I'm building a React app, and it basically loads blog posts, and attached comments for each post.

When a blog post is rendered, the comments for that blog post are also fetched. I also have a component that allows a comment to be submitted.

When the submit button is clicked, I want the comments to refresh their data source, and immediately display the new comment.
How do i send some kind of event to our comments component that tells it to send another fetch request?

It seems that the core of this problem is this:

How do I idiomatically send events to other React components that will trigger an effect?

EDIT - General Solution:

1. Lift State up into nearest component
2. create a callback function that includes the state update function. Pass this callback as a prop to the component that will be triggering the event. When the event happens, run the callback in the handler.

### Post.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import Markdown from 'markdown-to-jsx';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import SendComment from './SendComment';
import Comments from './Comments';
import {POST_URL} from './urls';
import UserContext from './UserContext';
//import CommentListContainer from './CommentListContainer';

export default function Post(props) {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);

  const [post, setPost] = useState({
    content: '',
    comments: [],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const UNIQUE_POST_URL = [POST_URL, props.location.state.id].join('/');

    const fetchPost = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(UNIQUE_POST_URL);
      const json = await result.json();
      setPost(json);
    };
    fetchPost();
  }, [props.location.state.id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Typography
          variant="h4"
          color="textPrimary"
          style={{textDecoration: 'underline'}}>
          {post.title}
        </Typography>
        <Markdown>{post.content}</Markdown>
        {post.content.length !== 0 && (
          <div>
            <Typography variant="h4">Comments</Typography>
            <SendComment user={user} posts_id={props.location.state.id} />
            <Comments user={user} posts_id={props.location.state.id} />
          </div>
        )}
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### SendComment.js component

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import {COMMENT_SUBMIT_URL} from './urls';

export default function SendComment(props) {
  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    const comment = document.querySelector('#comment');

    // Skip empty comments
    if (comment.value === '') {
      return;
    }

    async function sendComment(url) {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            comment: comment.value,
            users_id: props.user.users_id,
            posts_id: props.posts_id,
          }),
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
          },
        });
        comment.value = '';
        return res;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    const res = await sendComment(COMMENT_SUBMIT_URL);
    if (res.ok) {
      // Reload our comment component !
      // Here is where we want to send our "event"
      // or whatever the solution is
    }
  }

  return (
    <Grid container justify="space-evenly" direction="row" alignItems="center">
      <Grid item xs={8}>
        <TextField
          id="comment"
          fullWidth
          multiline
          rowsMax="10"
          margin="normal"
          variant="filled"
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

### Comments.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ListItemAvatar from '@material-ui/core/ListItemAvatar';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import {timeAgo} from './utils';
import {COMMENT_URL} from './urls';

export default function Comments(props) {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState({
    objects: [],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getComments(posts_id) {
      const filter = JSON.stringify({
        filters: [{name: 'posts_id', op: 'equals', val: posts_id}],
      });

      try {
        COMMENT_URL.searchParams.set('q', filter);

        const res = await fetch(COMMENT_URL, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });
        const json = await res.json();
        setComments(json);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    getComments(props.posts_id);
  }, [props.posts_id]);

  const commentList = comments.objects.map(comment => (
    <ListItem key={comment.id} alignItems="flex-start">
      <ListItemAvatar>
        <Avatar alt={comment.users.name} src={comment.users.picture} />
      </ListItemAvatar>
      <ListItemText
        primary={`${comment.users.name} - ${timeAgo(comment.created_at)}`}
        secondary={comment.comment}></ListItemText>
      <Divider />
    </ListItem>
  ));

  return <List>{commentList}</List>;
}
```

This code currently works, However the new comment is displayed only on a page reload, not immediately after submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can send such events without any extra logic.

The easiest solution I see is the following: as soon as you have a parent component (`Post`) for both `SendComment` and `Comments`, you can move all logic into it. Instead of saving the comment inside `SendComment`, you could pass it a callback which would be triggered when the user presses the button. The comment then sould be sent to server inside `Post`.

To display comments, you can fetch them in `Post` as well and then just pass it to `Comments` as a prop. Like this you can easily update comments and you won't need an extra request when the user submits a new comment.

Also prefer using controlled components (you have an uncontrolled text field in `SendComment`)

Code would look something like this:

### Post.js

```
export default function Post(props) {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);

  const [content, setContent] = useState('')
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([])

  const onNewComment = useCallback((text) => {
    // I'm not sure about your comment structure on server. 
    // So here you need to create an object that your `Comments` component 
    // will be able to display and then do `setComments(comments.concat(comment))` down below
    const comment = { 
      comment: text,
      users_id: user.users_id,
      posts_id: props.location.state.id,
    };
    async function sendComment(url) {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(comment),
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
          },
        });
        return res;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    const res = await sendComment(COMMENT_SUBMIT_URL);
    if (res.ok) {
      setComments(comments.concat(comment));
    }
  }, [comments]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const UNIQUE_POST_URL = [POST_URL, props.location.state.id].join('/');

    const fetchPost = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(UNIQUE_POST_URL);
      const { content, comments, title } = await result.json();
      setContent(content);
      setComments(comments);
      setTitle(title);
    };
    fetchPost();
  }, [props.location.state.id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Typography
          variant="h4"
          color="textPrimary"
          style={{textDecoration: 'underline'}}>
          {title}
        </Typography>
        <Markdown>{content}</Markdown>
        {content.length !== 0 && (
          <div>
            <Typography variant="h4">Comments</Typography>
            <SendComment user={user} onNewComment={onNewComment} />
            <Comments user={user} comments={comments} />
          </div>
        )}
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### SendComment.js

```
export default function SendComment(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    // Skip empty comments
    if (comment.value === '') {
      return;
    }
    if(props.onNewComment) {
      props.onNewComment(text);
      setText('');
    }
  }, [props.onNewComment, text]);

  return (
    <Grid container justify="space-evenly" direction="row" alignItems="center">
      <Grid item xs={8}>
        <TextField
          id="comment"
          onChange={setText}
          fullWidth
          multiline
          rowsMax="10"
          margin="normal"
          variant="filled"
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

### Comments.js

```
export default function Comments(props) {
  const commentList = props.comments.map(comment => (
    <ListItem key={comment.id} alignItems="flex-start">
      <ListItemAvatar>
        <Avatar alt={comment.users.name} src={comment.users.picture} />
      </ListItemAvatar>
      <ListItemText
        primary={`${comment.users.name} - ${timeAgo(comment.created_at)}`}
        secondary={comment.comment}></ListItemText>
      <Divider />
    </ListItem>
  ));

  return <List>{commentList}</List>;
}
```

UPD: changed some code to display content and title in `Post.js`

Comment: Awesome, I think this is what I did, except all logic is moved up into `Post` instead of `SendComment`, and passed down as a callback. That certainly seems cleaner. I'm going to refactor it to this and try it out

Answer (score 1):

Here it goes an idea:

You should have your comments on a state variable in Posts.

Like so `const[comments, setComments] = useState([]);`.

You can recieve a prop in `SendComment`, named `onCommentSent`.
In your code, when you send a comment you execute `onCommentSent();`

So, in Posts, when the comment is sent, you reload the data of the comments and set it `comments` using `setComments(newData)`.
When the state reloads, the comments will refetch.

---

A better performing idea is to not to retrieve all comments on each comment POST request, you can update dinamically the data in the state variable `comments` knowing that next time that you fetch the server, the comment will come.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've created a working solution, however it is clearly ugly, and definitely feels like I'm brute forcing it, instead of doing it the React way:

I extracted the logic of fetching the comments into its own function. This function gets called during the effect, and inside of the `handleSubmit` function.

The `Comments` component is now a child of `SendComment` (which from an organizational standpoint makes no sense)

```
export default function SendComment(props) {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState({
    objects: [],
  });

  async function getComments(posts_id) {
    const filter = JSON.stringify({
      filters: [{name: 'posts_id', op: 'equals', val: posts_id}],
    });

    try {
      COMMENT_URL.searchParams.set('q', filter);

      const res = await fetch(COMMENT_URL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      const json = await res.json();
      setComments(json);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getComments(props.posts_id);
  }, [props.posts_id]);

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    const comment = document.querySelector('#comment');

    // Skip empty comments
    if (comment.value === '') {
      return;
    }

    async function sendComment(url) {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            comment: comment.value,
            users_id: props.user.users_id,
            posts_id: props.posts_id,
          }),
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
          },
        });
        comment.value = '';
        return res;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    const res = await sendComment(COMMENT_SUBMIT_URL);
    if (res.ok) {
      getComments(props.posts_id);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Grid
        container
        justify="space-evenly"
        direction="row"
        alignItems="center">
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <TextField
            id="comment"
            fullWidth
            multiline
            rowsMax="10"
            margin="normal"
            variant="filled"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container justify="space-left">
        <Grid item justify="flex-start">
          <Comments comments={comments} />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just a quick notice: you should better use `React.useCallback(cb, dependencies)` inside function components instead of writing functions only.
It is better for perfomance even though for async functions you'll have to do something like
`React.useCallback(() => (async() => { /* code goes here */ })(), [])`